# React Native Compile Update

Tags: react-native

Sempre que executo o comando ***react-native run-android*** aparecem alguns componentos no prompt de comando que solicitam atualização. Como esses:

```
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE   
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
```

Não encontrei referências na web de como atualizar esses componentes (UP-TO-DATE).

Já executei o comando ***react-native upgrade***, mas não era isso.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Mas up-to-date significa que já está atualizado

Comment: Sério? haha Aparece sempre... Pensei que fosse uma atualização disponível

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo tente rodar este **comando**:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: Iniciei outro projeto e não me deparei mais com o erro, vou aceitar sua resposta, já que foi a única.